# How to download more Firebase objects on RecyclerView Scroll?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that features chat rooms. Every room has an ID that serves as a database reference, and messages are brought down from there and displayed in a RecyclerView. I know how to increase the number of messages that are downloaded onCreate/onStart by using Query.orderbykey().limittolast(), but how do I download and display additional items when the user scrolls to the top of the RecyclerView of the chat activity, a la Facebook messenger?

Edit: Here is my adapter's construct0r:

```
public ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mMessage, ArrayList<String> mAuthor, String mRoomID, DatabaseReference reference) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mRoomID = mRoomID;
    numberOfRecentMessages=20;

    messageList = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabaseReference = reference.child(mRoomID+"_messages");
    recentMessages = mDatabaseReference.orderByKey().endAt(100).limitToLast(numberOfRecentMessages);
    recentMessages.addChildEventListener(mListener);

}
```

Comment: What's the error you get? Also: include a snippet of the JSON you query (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I get this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported. Here is an example of the query I am trying to download:

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit: since you're ordering by keys, and keys are by definition strings, you must pass a string. E.g. `.endAt("100")`. Note that the value `100`, must in that case be the key of an item. It is **not** an offset. I also just fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. I suppose I will still have to find a way to dynamically update that string to keep showing more messages on scroll. Is that possible? If so, could I do it with my numberOfMessages int when a the RecyclerView reaches the top?

Comment: You will need to track the first and last key that are currently visible. From there you can build the query to get the previous/next bunch of nodes. I recommend checking out a few of the other [questions about Firebase and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%5bandroid%5d%20pagination) as this was covered quite a few times before.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for `endAt()`, which takes the key of the last item to return. Say you you're currently showing these keys:

```
key20
key21
key22
key23
key24
key25
key26
key27
key28
key29
```

Then you can get the previous items with:

```
ref.orderByKey().endAt("key20").limitToLast(11)
```

Comment: It's crashing and requiring me to use the version of endAt with a String argument. Also, would I need to find a way to do this from the Chat activity? This code is currently sitting in the constructor of the adapter class

Comment: Right now, there is too much context needed, and none of it is shown. Since Stack Overflow is not a good interactive debugger: isolate the problem in a small piece of code, that has no external dependencies. Please edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the crash](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also include the complete stack trace in your post.